# Angular - How to call and activate a function from another component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular12

In my Angular-12 I have two components, employee-detail and employee-edit.

employee-detail.component.ts:

```js
profileTemplate: boolean = false;
contactTemplate: boolean = false;

profileFunction() {
  this.profileTemplate = true;
  this.contactTemplate = false;
}

contactFunction() {
  this.profileTemplate = false;
  this.contactTemplate = true;
}
```

employee-detail.component.html

```
<div class="card-body">
  <div id="external-events">
    <button (click)="profileFunction()" type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Profile</button>
    <button (click)="contactFunction()" type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-success">Contact</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div *ngIf="profileTemplate" class="card card-default color-palette-box">

</div>

<div *ngIf="contactTemplate" class="card card-default color-palette-box">

</div>
```

From the above code, the function on the button click determines which of the two divs is visible.
Now I have another component, employee-edit.

employee-edit.component.ts:

```js
onSubmitProfile() {
  this.router.navigate(['/employees-detail', this._id]);
}

onSubmitContact() {
  this.router.navigate(['/employees-detail', this._id]);
}
```

What I want to achieve is that when `onSubmitProfile()` is called it should activate `profileFunction()` and make

```
<div *ngIf="profileTemplate" class="card card-default color-palette-box">
```

visible, else if it is `onSubmitContact()` it should be

```
<div *ngIf="contactTemplate" class="card card-default color-palette-box">
```

How do I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: You want to look at `EventEmitter` and `@Output` bindings

Comment: @GaëlJ - How do I do that?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution 1: [Fragment](https://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/build-a-simple-angular-service-to-share-data/)

**1.1** Pass the event (contact or profile) in the `fragment` with [`NavigationExtras`](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#navigate).

> employee-edit.component.ts

```js
export class EmployeeEditComponent implements OnInit {

  onSubmitProfile() {
    this.router.navigate(['/employees-detail', this._id], {
      fragment: 'contact'
    });
  }

  onSubmitContact() {
    this.router.navigate(['/employees-detail', this._id], {
      fragment: 'contact'
    });
  }
}
```

**1.2** Retrieve `fragment` from `activatedRoute` and do the action based on `fragment`.

> employee-detail.component.ts

```js
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

export class EmployeeDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.fragment.subscribe(fragment => {
      if (fragment == 'profile') this.profileFunction();
      else if (fragment == 'contact') this.contactFunction();
    });
  }
}
```

[Sample Solution 1 on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qasvyb)

**Benefit**: Easier to implement and manipulate content with fragment `#event`.

**Disadvantage**: The URL will show the fragment `#event` since it is implemented.

---

### Solution 2: [Build Simple Service to Share Data](https://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/build-a-simple-angular-service-to-share-data/)

**2.1** Create `EmployeeEventService` with getter and setter methods for `event$`.

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EmployeeEventService {
  private event$: BehaviorSubject<
    keyof typeof EVENT | null
  > = new BehaviorSubject(null as keyof typeof EVENT | null);

  setEvent(event: keyof typeof EVENT) {
    this.event$.next(event);
  }

  getEvent() {
    return this.event$.asObservable();
  }
}

export enum EVENT {
  contact,
  profile
}
```

**2.2** Inject `EmployeeEventService` and set the event via `setEvent()`.

```js
import { EmployeeEventService } from '../employee-event.service';

export class EmployeeEditComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    public employeeEventService: EmployeeEventService
  ) {}

  onSubmitProfile() {
    this.employeeEventService.setEvent('profile');
    this.router.navigate(['/employees-detail', this._id]);
  }

  onSubmitContact() {
    this.employeeEventService.setEvent('contact');
    this.router.navigate(['/employees-detail', this._id]);
  }
}
```

**2.3** Inject `EmployeeEventService` and get `event$` Observable via `getEvent()`.

```js
import { EmployeeEventService } from '../employee-event.service';

export class EmployeeDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    public employeeEventService: EmployeeEventService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.employeeEventService.getEvent().subscribe(event => {
      if (event == 'profile') this.profileFunction();
      else if (event == 'contact') this.contactFunction();
    });
  }
}
```

[Sample Solution 2 on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ggahfp)

**Benefit**: Control `event` by the service (Benefit for Solution 1's disadvantage).

**Disadvantage**: Harder to implement compared to Solution 1.

Comment: I decided to use Solution 2. But got this error in the service:   Type 'BehaviorSubject<null>' is not assignable to type 'BehaviorSubject<"contact" | "profile">'.
  Types of property 'value' are incompatible.
    Type 'null' is not assignable to type '"contact" | "profile"'.ts(2322).     Then, event$  is highlighted

Comment: Hi, updated my answer. By applying this `private event$: BehaviorSubject<keyof typeof EVENT | null> = new BehaviorSubject(null as keyof typeof EVENT | null);`, as `event$` allows null.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am gratefull